# Ajax call passing string to webservice and getting String[] back

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, web-services

I'm new to Ajax and webservices and trying to make an Ajax call in my Javascript code which pass a string to my webservice method (C#).
Afterwards the webservice method have to return a string array which I want to loop through in my Ajax success method.
Do anyone know how to realize that?

My not working attempt:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MyWebService.asmx/getMembers",
    data: groupname,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert("Success");
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            alert(JSON.parse(data[i]));
        }
    }
});
```

"groupname" is a string variable and "data" should be an array.
Any suggestions?

Should I use "text" for the contentType and is there a dataType: "String[]"?

webservice code:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public String[] getMembers(String groupname)
    {
        ...
        return userArray;
    }
```

The webservice method works. I have tested it writing the result into a CSV file. So the Problem must be the parameter or the return value.

Comment: can you do `console.log(data)` and show what is the result

Comment: 1-what is "not working"? be more specific please, 2-To see anything the server code is needed.

Comment: Have you verified that your url is actually returning something? Post the logs of whatever your server returns

Comment: The error method of the Ajax call returns parsererror. It never reach the success method, thats what not working. I think it's because it Returns a String[] and the Ajax call expect some json.

Answer (score 0):

Warning : cannot test.

**Server side**

Set a JSON content-type response header in your webservice and populate a JSON object :

```
private class Payload
{
    public String[] payload;
}    
...
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string getMembers(String groupname)
{
    ...
    Payload p = new Payload();
    // populate
    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(p); 
}
```

Check by calling your webservice if you have something like this :

`{"payload":["string1","string2","string3"]}`

**Client side**

Keep the JSON contentType in your AJAX call then parse it in javascript :

```
...
success: function(data) {
    alert("Success");
    for (var i = 0; i < data.payload.length; i++) {
        alert(data.payload[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which datatype should I choose for the Parameter of the webservice method and which for the return value?

Comment: The parameter of the webservice stays `String` and you can use the JSON part of this tutorial to return the above JSON : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8ef97c/web-service-in-Asp-Net-part-4/ (TL:DR add `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] ` under `[WebMethod]` and return an object). Editing my answer

Comment: How do the data-parameter in the Ajax cool look like in your example?